# I didn't put function on args of component. What should I fix it? React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Compiler says

```
const Form = (
  submit: (email: string, password: string) => void, message:string)
  {
  return (//omit//)
  }



  const submitC = (
    userName: string,
    password: string
  ) => {
    props.submitC( email, pass);
  };



  <Form
          submit={submitC}
          message={""}
        />
```

Compiler says

is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ((email: string, password: string) => void)'.
  Property submit does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &  ((email: string, password: string) => void) => void)'.ts(2322)

Comment: try `[x:string]:any`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `Form` to be a functional component and you are using it below as `StudentForm`. I’m not sure why these don’t match, but I’ll answer based on that assumption.

Functional components can only have one parameter, typically called `props`, although it’s also common to destructure the parameters.

The jsx “attibutes” of `StudentForm` will get assembled into a single object for `Form`.

But `Form` has two separate parameters right now, `submit`, and `message`.

Try the following (edited to fix typing on complete object):

```
const Form = ({
    submit,
    message
}:{
    submit: (email: string, password: string) => void,
    message:string
}) =>
{
    return (//omit//)
}
```

Notice the extra braces that make `submit` and `message` destructured from a single object parameter, with the type specified after the complete object.